# Erro ao usar o ngFor no angular: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'

Tags: angular

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao usar a diretiva do ngFor no angular: ***Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.***

Este é o meu código:

***usuario.component.ts***

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Usuario } from '../usuario';
import { UsuarioService } from '../usuario.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usuario',
  templateUrl: './usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usuario.component.scss']
})
export class UsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
  public usuarios: Usuario[] = [
    {
      nome: "João Filipe",
      email: "joaofilipecb@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      nome: "Jesiel",
      email: "jesiel@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      nome: "Jamile",
      email: "jamile@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      nome: "Jéssica",
      email: "jessica@hotmail.com"
    }
  ]
  constructor(private usuarioService: UsuarioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

***usuario.module.ts***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class UsuarioModule { }
```

***usuario.component.html***

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nome
        </th>
        <th>
            E-mail
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios;">
        <td>{{usuario.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***app.module.ts***

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: **ngForOf** mas está utilizando **ngFor**

Comment: Como assim? Sou novo no Angular, não entendo muito bem.

Comment: No html que postou está utilizando ngFor e o erro que mostrou está indicando o uso do ngForOf.

Comment: Eu sei. Mas estou usando apenas o ngFor. E, mesmo assim, o erro persiste.

Comment: Quando eu removo o ngFor, o erro some. Essa é a prova que está atrelado ao ngFor.

Comment: Cara estranho pq esse erro dá quando não é utilizado o CommonModule no módulo que está utilizando o ngFor, que não é o caso aí. Realmente não sei o pq do erro!

Comment: O app.module.ts e usuario.module.ts estão corretos então deveria estar funcionando. Tenta apagar a pasta node_modules depois dá um npm install e um ng serve para ver se o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: @brenodiogo, acabei de fazer, o erro ainda persiste. :/

Comment: seu app.module.ts está correto? Lá nas declarations não tem o UsuarioComponent, então o angular nem deveria estar compilando